# Stackoverflow activity tracker

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

Do somebody knows desktop utility to track activity on stackoverflow?
I would like be notified when question in featured domain appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:
http://code.google.com/p/open-so-frontend/

and here (you need Firefox and Greasemonkey plug-in for these):
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey

Answer (score 1):

Each page on Stack Overflow has an associated RSS feed. In particular, if you want to keep an eye on the posts for a particular tag, subscribe to that tag in your RSS reader.

For example, the RSS feed for questions tagged "subjective" is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/subjective
```

Comment: It rather curious to check feeds from approximately 150 tags of mine

Comment: You can combine tags into a single feed too, but I forget the exact syntax to do that.